# RichTextFormat as variable type

Tags: c#, variables, uwp, richeditbox

I am trying to make a  Universal Windows Platform (UWP) program where I have a RichEditBox that allows me to write Richly Formatted Text for several separate objects. I want to be able to click on an object and then display the text associated with that object.

Click on object -> RichEditBox displays the text in RTF (Rich Text Format) of that object.

Click on another object -> RichEditBox now displays the text belonging to the latest object.

Currently I am only able to hold the input as a string, but this loses the formatting of the input (specifically the colors of the words).

How do I hold my input (keep the data in RAM) in a way that allows me to retain the formatting?

Is there a certain variable type I can use?

Comment: you mean you have may have a string and an image beside it and when you select the string/text from the REB, you want to get the image next to it too ?

Comment: No. I want to have a list of variables where each variable holds the text in RTF of the input that the user typed in. Using a string type wont do as that does NOT retain the different colors of the different words.

Comment: You mean : If user types `Hello good morning` , you need to have a list of the words `Hello` , `Good` , `Morning` ?

Comment: No. If user types: "public static main(string [] args)" I wish to be able to set a color for each word. Example: public in blue. static in purple. To do this I use a RichEditBox and the RichTextFormat. Now I want to save this Input in a variable (like a string), but without losing the coloring of the words. How can I store (in RAM, not harddrive) the information that is in the RichTextFormat?

Comment: It may seem a bit complicated..but i've done it.. i will try to post an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for the Problem. I need to save the input in the RichEditBox as a InMemoryRandomAccessStream.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    // The variable to hold the input
    Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = 
    new Windows.Storage.Streams.InMemoryRandomAccessStream(); 


    public void storeInput()
    {
        RichEditBox.Document.SaveToStream
        (Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, stream);
    }
}
```